# Deleting duplicate nodes in singly linked list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to delete duplicate nodes in a singly linked list: [1,1,2] would return [1,2].

So I would check `if head.val == head.next`, and if so, set `head.val = null`. However, in Javascript, null apparently returns an object. So now my output would be [[],1,2] instead of the desired [1,2].

```
var deleteDuplicates = function(head) {
    if (!!(head && head.next)) {
        if (head.val === head.next.val) {
            head.val = null;
        }
    }
    return head;
};
```

How can I get it to return [1,2]?

P.S. this is a coding question from Leetcode - I'm just wondering how I can set the value to nothing instead of null, which is an object.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Tibrogargan it's been added.

Comment: Is your linked list sorted?

Comment: Yes, it's sorted. Please understand the scope of the question - all I'm asking is, how can I not return an object when I set it to null?

Comment: change `head.val = null;` to `head.next = head.next.next;`

Comment: You don't want to be setting value to null, but setting the next to skip.  `head.next = head.next.next`  also your function is not iterative so would only delete one duplicate..

Comment: @Keith, what happens when there is no head.next.next? In the case of [1,2,3,3], the first 3's `head.next.next` would be null.

Comment: You would want it to be null..  ps. @Teemu this is NOT a duplicate of your link, a javascript array is not a single linked list, either un-mark this as a duplicate, or link to a question that does have single linked list in it that removes duplicates.